# Interpreting an interaction effect with a logged term

Tags: regression, interaction

I am researching what effect transport infrastructure quality has on political stability. I would like to add an interactive term  - population density. I wish to investigate the effect that improving transport infrastructure by 1 point has on political stability in countries with differing population densities.

I computed an interactive variable by multiplying population per square mile with quality of transport infrastructure. I included this term in my regression, along with the the original population density variable and the quality of transport variable and obtained the following output.
[image]
My question is, how do I interpret the resulting model?
The population density variable has been log transformed and this is what is causing me a headache.

(I know that the interactive term is insignificant - but I must include an interpretation regardless for my university paper)

Comment: You have an interpretation for the $\mathit{lnpopdens}$ variable correct? The interaction term would pickup how that effect varies linearly with transport infrastructure quality. It's a second derivative.

Comment: Matthew, thank you for your reply. Sorry to say though that it has gone completely over my head! If you are able to start from the beginning with your explanation it would be most appreciated, though I understand if you don't have the time. I am very new to all of this and I don't know what a second derivative is. I just wish to know how to interpret the effect that population density has on the relationship between infrastructure quality and political stability,

Comment: Have you done calculus? Eg. if we have $f(x) = a + bx$ then $\frac{df}{dx} = b$, the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is $b$; the slope of the line is $b$?

Comment: I have not studied calculus no - thank you for what you have written below but once again that is way beyond me. I have purely been taught how to enter variables into spss and how to interpret the very basic outputs. I have not however been taught how to interpret them when variables have been log transformed (as they were skewed). I really appreciate you taking the time to help though :)

Comment: Hehe, my last try! With linear regression, you're estimating the [slope of a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope). The interaction term shows you how the slope of the line changes as another variable changes.

Comment: The interpretation of the main effects is complicated by the cross product term so, in your case in which there is no evidence of an interaction, I would suggest leaving the cross product term out of the model. Although many people refer to a cross product term as an interaction, it contains main effects and interactions. Only when the main effects are partialled out (as they are in computing the regression coefficient) is the term an interaction. With the cross product term in the model, what looks like a main effect is actually a simple effect at the point at which the other variable is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Linear regression as a conditional expectation function

One interpretation of what you're doing with linear regression is that you're estimating a linear conditional expectation function. You're approximating the conditional expectation of $y$ given $x$ with a line.

Let's say you run the regression:

$$ y_i = a + b x_i + \epsilon_i$$

Because of the assumption $\operatorname{E}[\epsilon \mid X] = 0$, the expectation of $y$ given $x$ is then:

$$ \operatorname{E}\left[y \mid x \right] = a + b x$$

You're approximating the conditional expectation of $y$ given $x$ with a line. Your effect $b$ is the slope of the line. Let's call $f(x) = a  + bx$. The slope of your line is $\frac{df}{dx} = b$.

(Note that estimating a conditional expectation function can be useful for forecasting with minimal assumptions, but if you want to say $b$ is a *causal* effect, this requires more assumptions on the data generating process.)

#### With interaction terms:

Let's say you add another variable $z$, add an interaction term $xz$, and run the regression:

$$ y_i = b_0 + b_1 x_i + b_2 z_i + b_3 x_i z_i + \epsilon _i $$

Your conditional expectation of $y$ given $x$ and $z$ would be given by:

$$ f(x, z) = \operatorname{E}[y \mid x, z] = b_0 + b_1 x_i + b_2 z_i + b_3 x_i z_i$$

What is the effect of $x$? the derivative with respect to $x$?

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = b_1 + b_3 z_i $$

The effect of $x$ varies linearly with $z$. If you take the 2nd derivative:

$$\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\,\partial z} = b_3$$